# ranking where the score is a function of time

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I would like to migrate my db which is currently on mysql to C*. At the moment I have a table that I have trouble imagining how to "migrate" it.

**Entity**

- Id
- score(s)
- hotscore

Where hotscore is f(s,d) = log10 + (s.t/45000). S is score and t is timestamp since epoch.

Essentially what I would be looking into querying is the top 20 of that entity. With mysql and a cron job I'm updating the hotscore every minute. For that reason hot score cannot be suited for a partition key. I'm trying to see if I can make this happen before moving to c*. As far as I know a primary key like `(id, hotscore)` wouldn't be good because it means C* has to scan every entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll soon be able to handle this use case with materialized views when Cassandra 3.0 is released.

See an example of ordering rows in a materialized view [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-in-cassandra-3-0-materialized-views) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014367/cassandra-list-10-most-recently-modified-records/32017197#32017197).

The way it works is in your base table you don't use the score as a clustering column, but you do use it as a clustering column in the materialized view.  Then when you update the base table, the ordering in the view is automatically updated.

Comment: Great ! on a side note I'm currently reading about ScyllaDB that claims to be a better version of cassandra, 10x faster, "plug-and-play" type. Do you know about that ?

Comment: I read a little about ScyllaDB and it sounds interesting.  I wanted to try it, but strangely there doesn't seem to be a version for Ubuntu yet.  I think the 10x number comes from a single node cluster test, which seems like a strange test case.  They really need to test large clusters to make a good comparison.  The idea of using C++ instead of java and sharding the CPU cores seems like it could give a good performance boost, but time will tell.  I'm actually more interested in getting full SQL support into C* than more performance, but more performance is always welcome too.