# Is there a way for Cassandra to ignore clustering key when inserting?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

Right now I have a table with three columns: `GroupId`,`ObjectId` and `Data`, with first two defined as partition key.

Currently it works as desired: if  `GroupId`and `ObjectId` match existing row, it gets overwritten.

I'm trying to add sorting by date, so I added third column, `LastModified` and specified it as clustering key. While it works for sorting, now I have multiple rows sharing the same `GroupId`and `ObjectId` pairs, which is not what I need.

How can I achieve previous behaviour?

1. I could read table before writing and delete matching row before writing a new one.
2. I could, after reading, filter rows in my application.

I dislike both solutions because they seem to be too complicated and performance is a big concern. Is there a better way?

Comment: Guess this thread solves your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014367/cassandra-list-10-most-recently-modified-records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i did this in case someone else faces same problem:

I have a table with `GroupId` and `ObjectId` as key. I'm not sure if it matters, but `ObjectId` is defined as clustering key.

Then you get desired result from following view:

```
        CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS objectlistbylast
        AS SELECT * FROM objectlist
        WHERE groupid IS NOT NULL AND objectid IS NOT NULL AND lastmodified IS NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY(groupid , lastmodified, objectid )
        WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY(lastmodified DESC);
```

**Note that ordering when defining primary key matters.**